# Update {{alert.currentPage}} in directive on each route change in angular-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Mainly I am trying to figure out how to update alert.currentPage for each route. I switched everything to a directive but still am at a loss. Any direction would be helpful.

Thanks!

**REWRITTEN ALL CODE BASE**
index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mydh" ng-controller="mainController">
<head>
<title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/app-dashboard.css">
  <script src="assets/javascript/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/javascript/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/javascript/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/javascript/app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/javascript/app/app-template.js"></script>
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
  <page-navigation></page-navigation>
  <page-alerts></page-alerts>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <page-footer></page-footer>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('mydh', ['ngRoute', 'mydhTemplate']);

    app.directive('pageAlerts', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'tmpl/alerts.html',
            controller: function() {
                this.currentPage = 'Dashboard';
            },
            controllerAs: 'alert'

        };
    });

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/mydash.html',
            controller  : 'dashController',
        })

        .when('/wizard', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/wizard.html',
            controller  : 'wizardController',
        })

        .when('/reporting', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/reporting.html',
            controller  : 'reportingController',
        })

        .when('/billing', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/billing.html',
            controller  : 'billingController',
        })

        .when('/catalog', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/catalog.html',
            controller  : 'catalogController',
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

    app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.pageTitle   = 'Demo Page';

    });

})();
```

tmpl/alerts.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</li>
                <li class="active">{{ alert.currentPage }}</li>
                <li class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <strong><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Alert:</strong> Placeholder for alert information, if we ever need to display something crital! <a href="#" class="alert-link">Read more...</a>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Info:</strong> Placeholder for any information alerts we may want to display. <a href="#" class="alert-link">Read more...</a>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure your demo works, right now it throws errors.

Comment: yeah, i'm aware. I was hoping someone could just look at the code and tell me what I was doing wrong - I don't know how to use plunker unfortunately

Comment: DOM manipulation shouldn;t be a part of controller..you should think of directive..

Comment: app structure doesn't make sense. No `<ng-view>`. Your route controllers are scoped for inside `<ng-view>` but the include is outside of it. Can create a directive for alerts and service to share your page data bewtween controllers and directive

Comment: there is a div ng-view?

Comment: OK...I see one in code posted here but not in demo. Issue is still the same rgearding controller scopes. Also note that `ng-include` creates child scope. Would suggest you create own directives for header,footer, alerts etc

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding currentPage property in routeProvider and then throwing this bad boy in:

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$route) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(currentRoute, previousRoute) {
        $rootScope.currentPage = $route.current.currentPage;
    });
});
```